# How to find a variable is cached or not by looking at code?

Tags: caching, memory

In an interview recently I was asked a strange question :
"How to find if a variable is cached or not just by looking at the code"

I could not satisfy the interviewers with below answers:

**1.** If a variable is cached then time taken to read or update will be less and is indicative of whether the variable is cached or not.

**2.** In a debugger (like Trace 32), you can halt the execution of core and then update the variable value, and then disable MMU and check the content of the variable. In case the value remains same then it's non cached, otherwise it's cached.

Any thoughts on this problem ?

Comment: I would say that you did not satisfy them because you ignored an important part of the question: "just by looking at the code". You only enumerated other things, but nothing code-related.

Comment: I don't know the answer to how you can do it, but those two answers are not "just looking at the code" so they would not answer the question anyway. I am pretty certain this would depend on the definition of "cached" in the interview context, and what kind of programming language this is, so it's kinda impossible for us here to provide any thoughts.

Comment: Perhaps the answer they were looking for is "you can't"?  I would have countered with "if the success of your project relies on whether a particular variable is cached or not, then you are already in trouble".

Comment: Language used is c here. I feel looking at code its just impossible. Maybe if they consider linker files or .map files also as code !!! Maybe any #pragma in code can be indicative of cached/non-cached. But even if i consider these points can we still deduce anything ?